# Sending Json data as an object into DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have been trying to use DataTables. But after my Ajax request i get a Json object which i cannot pass into dataTables.

The Json object i receive is the following

```
{"data": [{"attributes": {"purchasedate": "04/01/2017", "medication": "meds", "cost": 100.0, "expirydate": "04/03/2017", "quantity": 100.0}, "type": "medical_inventory"}, {"attributes": {"purchasedate": "04/01/2017", "medication": "Extra Meds", "cost": 100.0, "expirydate": "04/02/2017", "quantity": 100.0}, "type": "medical_inventory"}, {"attributes": {"purchasedate": "04/01/2017", "medication": "Extra Super Meds", "cost": 267.0, "expirydate": "04/11/2017", "quantity": 250.0}, "type": "medical_inventory"}], "links": {"self": "/medical_inventory/"}}
```

Following is my HTML code

```
<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Medication</th>
            <th>Medication Quantity</th>
            <th>Mediaction Cost</th>
            <th>Purchase Date</th>
            <th>Expiry Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Medication</th>
            <th>Medication Quantity</th>
            <th>Mediaction Cost</th>
            <th>Purchase Date</th>
            <th>Expiry Date</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The Ajax request i do is the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : '/api/medical_inventory/',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                assignToEventsColumns(data);
            }
        });

        function assignToEventsColumns(data) {
            var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "bAutoWidth" : false,
                "aaData" : data,
                "columns" : [ {
                    "data" : "medication"
                }, {
                    "data" : "quantity"
                }, {
                    "data" : "cost"
                }, {
                    "data" : "purchasedate"
                }, {
                    "data" : "expirydate"
                } ]
            })
        }
    });
```

[This is the output i am currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gpzs.png)

Comment: what is the `attributes` property for?

Comment: That's the Json return format I'm getting.. I don't know how to parse it into the type required by the dataTables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very nearly there:

```
function assignToEventsColumns(data) {
    var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aaData": data.data,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "attributes.medication"
        }, {
            "data": "attributes.quantity"
        }, {
            "data": "attributes.cost"
        }, {
            "data": "attributes.purchasedate"
        }, {
            "data": "attributes.expirydate"
        }]
    })
}
```

All you were missing was the structure of your JSON, you needed to add `attributes.` as well as your `data.data` :-D.Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/snLudd55/).

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the data to remove the `attributes` property of each object

```
success : function(data) {
   data.data = data.data.map(function(item){
      return item.attributes;
  });
  assignToEventsColumns(data);
}
```